# How can I enumerate through a HashSet?

Tags: c#

I have an object defined like this:

```
public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

I need to check each of the Questions in the object `problem` and manipulate some data.  Here's what I have tried:

```
foreach (Question question in problem)
{
    if (question.AssignedTo == null)
    {
        question.QuestionStatusId = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        question.AssignedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        question.QuestionStatusId = 5;
    }
}
```

But this does not work. I get an error message saying:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Entities.Models.Core.Problem' because 
>   'Entities.Models.Core.Problem' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Is there another way that I can do this? Note that the reason I used `new HashSet<Question>` was because I was told this is the way to do this if there are unique questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to iterate over the `HashSet` that is contained in the `Problem`, not the `Problem` itself:

```
foreach (Question question in problem.Questions) {
    ...
}
```

Due to the nature of the `HashSet`, though, the questions might come out in any order. If you want to maintain a particular order for the questions, you should use a `List`. It is true that the elements of a `HashSet` are unique, but that doesn't mean that you *have* to use a `HashSet` if your elements are unique.

Comment: Just a note, it is possible to maintain a particular order with a SortedSet.