# Why I cannot add Items into DataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to dynamically add new records to `DataGrid`. I'm using HashSet to prevent duplicates. But when I want to add objects from `HashSet` to `ObservableCollection`, I get the error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>.

I have implemented `IEnumerable`.

Constructor in `AdminWindow.xaml.cs` class:

```
public AdminWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<Alert> alertToDataGrid = new ObservableCollection<Alert>();
           
    for (int i = 0; i < Alert.alerts.Count; i++)
    {
        alertToDataGrid.Add(Alert.alerts[i]); //Here is the issue
    }

    AlertTable.ItemsSource = alertToDataGrid;
}
```

`Alert` class:

```
public class Alert : IEnumerable<Alert>
{
    private string id;
    private DateTime date;
    private string email;
    private string nameOfAlert;
    private string typeOfAlert; // will be enum later
    public static HashSet<Alert> alerts = new HashSet<Alert>();
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id + "\n" + Date+  "\n" + email + "\n" + nameOfAlert + "\n" + typeOfAlert;
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Alert alert &&
                            id == alert.id &&
                            Id == alert.Id;
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(id, Id);
    }

    // Tried just to return Enumerator
    public IEnumerator<Alert> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Alert alert in alerts)
        {
            yield return alert;
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    
    public Alert(string id, DateTime date , string email, string nameOfAlert, string typeOfAlert)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Email = email;
        this.NameOfAlert = nameOfAlert;
        this.TypeOfAlert = typeOfAlert;
    }
    
    public string Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
    public string NameOfAlert { get => nameOfAlert; set => nameOfAlert = value; }
    public string TypeOfAlert { get => typeOfAlert; set => typeOfAlert = value; }
    public DateTime Date { get => date; set => date = value; }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the ObservableCollection is totally redundant. You could as well write `AlertTable.ItemsSource = Alert.alerts;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try

```
foreach (Alert alert in Alert.alerts) {
  alertToDataGrid.Add(alert);
}
```

See [How can I enumerate through a HashSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410570/how-can-i-enumerate-through-a-hashset) for more details

Comment: Thanks to everybody for respond I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can't use the indexing for a `HashSet`. If you're that insistent of using a `HashSet`, you can try `alertToDataGrid.Add(Alert.alerts.ElementAt(i));`. You'll need to have `System.Linq` included.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `[]` i.e. indexing operator on `HashSet` as it is unordered data structure which does not support indexing. So it is not about `DataGrid` but about `HashSet` insterad of `for` loop please use `foreach` loop to iterate over `HashSet` or any other `IEnumerable` which does not support indexing.